# Throwing SAXException

Tags: java, xml, exception, null, sax

Learning xml parsing with Java, and am working in a test program to try things out as I go. All of the test System.out.println()'s were what I expected in the console except childElement was returning [name: null] and childElement.getNodeValue() was returning null rather than [name: "Branch Name"] and "Branch Name" respectively.

In an effort to correct that I started tweaking and of course broke the program further. Now, I'm throwing a SAXException (I've marked the line that I've narrowed it down to with a comment, although I'm not exactly clear on what a SAXException means, etc) when I try to run and I can't seem to get her back to where she was before.

Here's where the codes at now:

```
package uploaders;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException { 
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String appendage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><branch0><name>Branch Name</name></branch0>";
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
            System.out.println("Test Results:");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()); 

            Document doc = builder.parse(input); //originally org.w3c.dom.Document...this line is where SAXException is thrown.
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
            NodeList children = root.getChildNodes();

            System.out.println(root.getTagName());
            xmlStringBuilder.append(appendage); //forgot to move this up too (thanks @Vihar)

            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                Node child = children.item(i);
                if (child instanceof Element) { 
                    Element childElement = (Element) child; 
                    System.out.println(childElement.getTagName());
                    System.out.println(childElement.getNodeValue());
                    System.out.println(childElement); }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Any help with the SAXException is much appreciated, and after that I'll still probably need to figure out why the "name" element returns "null", but first things first :).

***Updated***
Shown in comments what was causing the SAXException. Console is still displaying this however:

```
Test Results:

/Users/.../Documents/java/Test/./bin
branch0
name
null           //I'm expecting "Branch Name"
[name: null]   //and "[name: Branch Name]"
```

***Finally***

```
childElement.getNodeValue() //needed + .toString() to work or:
childElement.getNodeValue().toString()
```

or

```
childElement.getTextContent()
```

Comment: After moving `xmlStringBuilder.append(appendage);` before `ByteArrayInputStream input = ...` (thanks @Vihar) I no longer get the SAXException, but still getting "null" rather than "Branch Name" in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies here

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

you have just created an empty object of StringBuilder(xmlStringBuilder) and are expecting to parse that, so compiler throws a `SAXParseException`

but you really need to **do this**

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(appendage.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

as you `appendage` string contains the actual xml information

**or do this**

```
xmlStringBuilder.append(appendage);   //I have just changed the sequence of these lines in your code
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document doc = builder.parse(input);
```

hope this helps!

good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! I moved the lines around earlier and now I've put `xmlStringBuilder.append(appendage);` before `ByteArrayInputStream input -= ...` and that took care of the SAXException. Still returning "null" for the childElement though...maybe I need a toString call?

Comment: @JamesLingo try doing `childElement.getTextValue()`

Comment: @JamesLingo if the answer helped you, acccept the answer

Comment: _@Vihar was definitely planning on it, just fell asleep :) For some reason Eclipse isn't accepting `childElement.getTextValue()`, and is recommending `childElement.getNodeValue()` which hasn't been working. Maybe I messed up the inheritance/need to implement the feature/or import a library?

Comment: Tried `childElement.getNodeValue().toString()` and that did the trick! I guess I should have realized the NodeValue would need to be formatted...still I'd rather have skipped the NodeValue() getter and used `.getTextValue()` or something similar. Any ideas on what I was missing?